# Помощь с ботом ВК (php)

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Использую `CallBackAPI`.

Не отправляется ответ на сообщение `Привет`.
Сервер подтвердил, токен подтверждения правильный.
Думаю не правильно функцию написал.

Без функции, все работает отлично.

```php
<?php

if (!isset($_REQUEST)) {
return;
}
$confirmation_token = '2b9034db';
$token = 'тут мой токен сообщества';
function msgnew ($user_id, $text)
{
    $request_params = array(
    'message' => $text,
    'user_id' => $user_id,
    'access_token' => $token,
    'v' => '5.50'
    );
$get_params = http_build_query($request_params);
file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?'. $get_params);
}

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

switch ($data->type) {
case 'confirmation':
    echo $confirmation_token;
break;

case 'message_new':
$bodycase = $data->object->body;
$user_id = $data->object->user_id;

    if ($bodycase == "Привет")
    {
        msgnew ($user_id, "Привет");
    }

echo 'ok';
break;

}
?>
```

**UPD:**
Использую `php://input`, чтобы декодировать входящий запрос `JSON`, в строку.
Дальше уже `switch` выбирает, тип входящего запроса.
Моя функция описывает только ответ на входящий запрос `'message_new'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```php
function msgnew ($user_id, $text, $token)
```

Решением оказалось добавление параметра $token в параметрах функции, т.к функция не имела $token описанный выше, соответственно не имела доступа к группе.

Comment: Советую делать отладку на локальном и включить все предупреждения и ошибки, а обновку кидать на боевом сервере, тогда у вас такого не будет возникать.